# Extract mail id from Script

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, sh

Use this shell script as source to extract mail id fields . Need to extract the mail ids alone. For example need to take 
anupam.panda@btx.com
ajay.k.singh@btx.com
Please advice.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#exit 0
export nodename=`uname -n`
export SENDER_ID=BTFON.$nodename@btx.com
mailx -s "ERROR: OWB loading for ${FILE_NAME} has failed " anupam.panda@btx.com,ajay.k.singh@btx.com <<EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If directory to scan (recursively) is MYDIR then:

```
grep -hrioI '[a-z0-9_\.]\+@[a-z0-9]\+\.[a-z0-9\.]\{2,\}' MYDIR 2>/dev/null | sort -u
```

If you only want to scan shell scripts add --include=*.sh option:

```
grep -hrioI --include=*.sh '[a-z0-9_\.]\+@[a-z0-9]\+\.[a-z0-9\.]\{2,\}' MYDIR 2>/dev/null | sort -u
```

**EDIT** I have changed the pattern for TLD to be at least 2 symbols ({2,} instead of +).

Comment: This is great. If I need the line numbers or name of the script where the mail id is used.

Comment: In that case it would be grep -rnioI '[a-z0-9_\.]\+@[a-z0-9]\+\.[a-z0-9\.]\{2,\}' $MYDIR 2>/dev/null . Notice that in this case the last " | sort -u" is useless as we print file name and line number.

Comment: Result is extra ordinary. Is there similar way to search ksh script inside instead of email ids??

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you can search within files by extension, e. g. if your korn shell scripts have '*.ksh' extension you can add --include=\*.ksh option to grep as in my second example above.

Comment: Its other way. In a shell scripts , i will be calling lot of other ksh scripts in the format ksh <script_name>.ksh or ./<script_name>.ksh or lot of other ways. I need to fetch the <script_name>.ksh as output. Do I make sense now?

Comment: grep -rnioIE '\<[^\ ]+\.ksh\>' MYDIR 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS="[\",<]" '/mailx/{for(i=3;i<NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

If your files have similar formatting and you wish to extract all emails which follow the subject line until <

To capture sender_id then do something like this -

```
awk -v FS="[\",<$]" '
/mailx/{print "RECEPIENTS: ";for(i=4;i<NF;i++) print $i;next}
/SENDER_ID/{print "SENDER INFO: \n"$NF}' file
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[\",<$]" '
/mailx/{print "RECEPIENTS: ";for(i=4;i<NF;i++) print $i;next}
/SENDER_ID/{print "SENDER INFO: \n"$NF}' file
SENDER INFO: 
nodename@btx.com
RECEPIENTS: 
 anupam.panda@btx.com
ajay.k.singh@btx.com
```

Comment: how do i make it to search for all the scripts?

Comment: how do I make it loop through more than one script in an directory?

Comment: Instead of `file` you can do something like this `awk -v ..' … ' <(find /path/to/files -type f -name "*.script")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Code:

```
awk -F\" '
    /^mailx/{
        n=split(substr($3,2,length($3)-6),emails,/,/)
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)print emails[i]}
    ' f3
```

Output:

```
anupam.panda@btx.com
ajay.k.singh@btx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^mailx/!d;s/.*"\s*\|\s*\S*$//g;y/,/\n/' file1 file2 file3 ...
anupam.panda@btx.com
ajay.k.singh@btx.com
```